# Xdebug remote debuggin - crashing on step over, step into etc

Tags: php, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, xdebug, puphpet

I have a virtual development environment in vagrant which I have provisioned using puphpet.com. Until today, everything was in perfect working order, but suddently - seemingly unrelated to my actions - Xdebug stopped working.

I use phpstorm for development and debugging and what happens is, I set a breakpoint in phpstorm, then I enable the remote debugging listener in phpstorm and the Chrome Xdebug Helper extension. When the code reaches the breakpoint, execution is paused and I am able to investigate the different variables, but as soon as I try to step through my code with either continue, step over or step into, phpstorm simply exits debug mode and my browser shows a 503 error.

I had a look at the syslog, which shows that it is a segmentation error, so not much in the way of clues there. Then I enabled the Xdebug log. I don't really know how to interpret it, but it seems to me that it logs that it was succesfully able to stop at a breakpoint and then when the error happens it just stops logging - which makes sense considering that it seems to be a segmentation error.

I tried updating xdebug with `pecl upgrade xdebug` and I tried running it on a port different from the port 9000 default. Did not change anything.

Any suggestions what I might try now?

My virtual machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64. PHP is v5.6.14 and Xdebug is v2.3.2.

Here is a link to my puphpet configuration in case it might help: https://gist.github.com/webconsult/dfa23f65ce2394624b0d

Comment: I have the same issue, have you figured it out in the meanwhile?

Comment: No, sorry. I have not. I would appreciate if someone can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue after researching the error I found the solution and it worked!
kindly add the lines at the end of php.ini same as given just change your path...

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I was using PHPStorm. What worked for me was to delete the .idea folder in the project's root folder and re open it with PHPStorm.